# WCF - large files upload - (413) Request Entity Too Large

Tags: c#, wcf

Can someone please take a look at my new code ? I'm stuck on this bug for 3 days now and it's driving me crazy...

I'm trying to have a WCF file upload, but large files are not uploaded

I'm getting this error: "The remote server returned an unexpected response: (413) Request Entity Too Large."

My project is built from 3 parts:

1. WCF service
2. a user control that uses the service
3. Web site that uses the user control

Here is my service we.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>

    <services>
      <service name="AttachmentService" behaviorConfiguration="">
        <endpoint name="DefaultEndPoint" address="http://localhost:54893/AttachmentService.svc"
                  behaviorConfiguration="EndpointBehaviors"
                  binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingName="AttachmentBinding"
                  contract="AttachmentsService.IAttachmentService"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>

      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="EndpointBehaviors">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="AttachmentBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" receiveTimeout="00:01:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                 textEncoding="utf-8" openTimeout="00:01:00">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Here is my user control app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IAttachmentService" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:54893/AttachmentService.svc"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IAttachmentService"
          contract="AttachmentsService.IAttachmentService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IAttachmentService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Here is my UI web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <serverRuntime enabled="true" uploadReadAheadSize="2147483647" maxRequestEntityAllowed="2147483647" />
  </system.webServer>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IAttachmentService" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:54893/AttachmentService.svc"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IAttachmentService"
          contract="AttachmentsService.IAttachmentService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IAttachmentService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

And here is how I've implemented the reference call:

```
public void UploadFile(string serviceUrl,decimal maxFileSize, AttachmentFileParams fileParams, Stream file)
{
    AttachmentServiceClient client = null;
    try
    {
        if (file.Length > (maxFileSize * 1024)) //maxFileSize is defined in KB and file.Length is in Bytes
                    return Serialization.ConvertToJson(new { IsError = true, ErrorMessage = Constants.Messages.MaxFileSizeExceeded + maxFileSize });

                string requestUrl = string.Format("{0}/UploadFile", serviceUrl);
                string jsonFile = Serialization.ConvertToJson(fileParams);
                byte[] jsonFileBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonFile);
                byte[] len = BitConverter.GetBytes(jsonFileBytes.Length);

                using (client = new AttachmentServiceClient())
                {
                    client.UploadFile(file);
                }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { }
    finally
    {
        try
                {
                    if (client.State != System.ServiceModel.CommunicationState.Closed)
                        client.Close();
                }
                catch
                {
                    client.Abort();
                }
    }
}
```

Is there anything I'm missing ?

Comment: May be this can help you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24932150/1660178

Comment: you need to use `transfermode` in your binding I guess.Follow https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789010(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I finally solved it and here are my config files that worked for me:

WCF service web.config file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    <services>
      <!-- The name of the service -->
      <service name="WcfService1.Service1">
        <!--you can leave the address blank or specify your end point URI-->
        <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="higherMessageSize" contract="WcfService1.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="Web" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <!-- configure the maxReceivedMessageSize value to suit the max size of the request (in bytes) you want the service to receive-->
        <binding name="higherMessageSize" transferMode="Streamed" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <!--<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" />-->
  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Client app.config / web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:59540/Service1.svc" behaviorConfiguration="webhttp"
        binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"
        contract="ServiceReference1.IService1" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webhttp">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I hope it will save other the time I've spent to solve it :-)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when uploading large files, with an IIS server.

I found there are two places you need to modify your `web.config`

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="50000"/>
</system.web>
```

and

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="50000000" />    <!-- Allow files of upto 50,000,000 bytes (about 50Mb) to be uploaded --> 
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Hope this helps.

More details here:
[Upload large files](http://www.mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/ASPNet/FileUpload.htm)